# dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules: array of bytes to a number

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning, strict-aliasing

I have already read a number of questions about this warning ([Dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246228/dereferencing-type-punned-pointer-will-break-strict-aliasing-rules), [Dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713851/dereferencing-type-punned-pointer-will-break-strict-aliasing-rules-wstrict-ali), [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule), ["dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163126/dereferencing-type-punned-pointer-will-break-strict-aliasing-rules-warning) and others) and got totally confused about my warning.

So I have a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char precision;
    unsigned char scale;
    unsigned char array[33];
} DBNUMERIC;
```

This struct is filled by FreeTDS library when retrieving data from MS SQL Server. I know that starting from `array[1]` there is 64-bit integral number (in big-endian) and I want to get it. I use the following code:

```
int64_t result = 0;
result = be64toh(*((decltype(result)*)(numeric.array + 1)));
```

But GCC gives me the warning `dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]`. But if I use the code:

```
int64_t result = 0;
decltype(result)* temp_ptr = (decltype(result)*)(numeric.array + 1);
decltype(result) temp = *temp_ptr;
result = be64toh(temp);
```

there are no warnings about violating strict-aliasing rules. I don't think that this code differs from the original, therefore I am confused. How can I convert 8 bytes from the array to a `int64_t` variable?

Comment: The [gcc strict aliasing warnings are not perfect](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25118277/1708801) and so are subject to false positives and false negatives depending on the setting.

Comment: Just use memcpy to type-pun see [this](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/959).

Comment: [Not reproducible here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/235334c24de643ee). Pointers to `char` and variants are explicitly exempt from strict aliasing rules, so a warning would not be justified.

Comment: @n.m. you have it backwards, `char*` is always allowed to alias not vice-versa. These warnings are version and optimization sensitive see [this live session](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DL11c37348yCKQHY).

Comment: If your hardware has alignment restrictions on `int64_t`, your `decltype(result) temp = *temp_ptr;` will likely result in a `SIGBUS`.  @ShafikYaghmour recommendation to use `memcpy()` is the proper way to access the data as an `int64_t`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour that's what I'm saying, not sure what exactly is backwards.

Comment: @n.m. you said *warning would not be justified* but it is definitely justified in this case.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour OK I see what you mean.

Comment: @n.m. great, for reference you can see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20956250/1708801) for the relevant details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of your cases violate the [strict aliasing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20956250/1708801). gcc's strict-aliasing warnings [are subject to false negatives and false positives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25117826/1708801) depending on the warning and optimization levels.

If you want to type-pun in a way not allowed by the strict aliasing rules then you should just use [std::memcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy):

```
std::memcpy(&result, numeric.array+1, sizeof(int64_t ));
```

We can see from the following sources; this article [Type Punning, Strict Aliasing, and Optimization](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/959) and the [std-dicussion conversation on type punning and unions I quote in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31080901/1708801) tell us that the compiler should be smart enough to optimize for the use of `memcpy` to generate efficient code.